# Pick a cluster for customer locations

Tags: r, clustering

On our app customer's visit stores. We would like to assign a City or location as the customer's "home" location, to offer him/her targeted offers. What we've done so far:

Using R, we performed DBSCAN (density based clustering) to cluster the stores the customer visited, we then have a a couple of outliers and clusters with N points each. We are struggling to pick one or two clusters out to assign as primary/secondary markets:

```
| cluster | points |  meanLat |  meanLon | City |
|---------|--------|----------|----------|------|
|       1 |    100 | X.XXXXXX | X.XXXXXX |    A |
|       2 |     20 | X.XXXXXX | X.XXXXXX |    B |
|       3 |     10 | X.XXXXXX | X.XXXXXX |    C |
```

For customer with this result, I think picking cluster 1 makes sense, but I'm failing to find a way to pick one programatically.

For our domain, it only makes sense to pick one if we are confident that the user visits these stores overwhelmingly and we know we might not be able to make the assignment if we have few data and we most wait for the user to visit more stores.

My concrete questions are:

**What makes *cluster 1* the right choice in this example? Is 130 points enough to pick 100?** What I have only 10 points total? Or, what if two clusters had 80 and 60 points? Where is the line?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a clustering problem what you are facing anymore.

The clusters are just a tool to help you understand the data. Do not assume they are 100% correct or anything. But a cluster may indicate e.g. that east coast and west coast customers exhibit different behavior. But it is then up to you to formalize and validate this concept. At this point it stopped being a clustering problem.

In your case there is no *statistical* answer to your question. The question whether to assign customers to one group or two is entirely a *business* decision to make, based on what you are doing with the data. Is not a property of the clustering.

Comment: I'm with you, clustering simply allowed me to group my observations into fewer. I could have used the City name to aggregate observations into a smaller set as well. Past that, are you saying there is no statistical way of qualifying these observations?  What if the problem was worded differently, without clustering?: "Guest 1, visited stores in city A 100 times, city B 20 times, city C 10 times, there is no statistical way of saying that the user is more likely to visit stores in city A in the future?"

Comment: You can do a MLE and you can also argue about estimation errors and confidence intervals if you make enough assumptions. Whether these assumptions are likely to hold or not *we* don't know. This is classic probability theory - it is better explained in the books than we will ever be able to do here because of length.

Comment: Thanks for the detail responses and pointers, I appreciate it. I'll read more about MLE and definitely hit the books for probability theory.